# javascript not working on native android browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I am part way through developing a mobile web app which contains almost no HTML elements. JSON2HTML is used to create HTML elements.

My problem is that it works ok *except* for on

- iPad
- Android 4.0.3 Native browser.

The problem with these browsers is that the content isn't being rendered.

It works fine on

- Android 4.0.3 Chrome,
- Android 4.0.3 Firefox
- Android 4.0.3 Opera
- Android 4.0.3 Dolphin
- Android 4.1.1 Native
- Android 4.1.1 Other browsers

Just to clarify, this is a mobile web app, not a native mobile app. I am not using any native code, I am using standard web technologies (HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Javascript, JSON)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of research and testing, I have found the solution.

1. First I activated the built-in debugger on my Android phone - instructions at http://tinyurl.com/768qltl
2. The debugger then told me that the error was at line 71 of jquery.json2html.js
3. I opened jquery.json2html.js
4. I replaced line 71 with the following code
   `else $.fn.append.call($(this),$(dom).children());`

This works because the previous line 71  was calling the jquery append.apply function, which only works with specific data type on older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be finding a way to remotely debug what's happening in the native browser. There are a couple ways to do this.

- Install an app like [JsHybugger](http://www.jshybugger.org/), which acts as a reverse proxy
- Add some new JavaScript to the source page and use [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/), [JSConsole](http://jsconsole.com/), or  to attach remotely